# How can I force gtk events during a long callback

Tags: gtk, glade

I need an event which handles press and release on toolbar button of my program.
I used button-press-event but when i click on my button nothing happens.

I'm designing my GUI using Glade Interface Designer. Please explain for me when button-press-event will be called in gtk+ & is it the event i need or not ?

'button-press-event' should give mouse button presses. I use gtk_widget_add_device_events () to add button presses to the list of events that are received by the button but I think it should get them by default.

```
gboolean
on_skip_backward_toolbutton_pressed (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event, gpointer user_data)
{
    g_print ("pressed");
    timeout_id = g_timeout_add(500, (GSourceFunc) change_freq_timeout, (gpointer) FALSE);

    return FALSE;
}

gboolean
on_skip_forward_toolbutton_pressed(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event, gpointer user_data)
{
    g_print ("pressed");
    timeout_id = g_timeout_add(500, (GSourceFunc) change_freq_timeout, (gpointer) TRUE);

    return FALSE;
}

gboolean
on_skip_toolbutton_released(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event, gpointer user_data)
{
    g_print ("released");
    if (timeout_id) {
        g_source_remove(timeout_id);
        timeout_id = 0;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

change_freq_timeout callback has a single instruction that takes a long time to process.

Running a mainiteration inside an timeout handler is generally considered `a bad idea' because it doesn't work very well.

Exist the other secret technique that can use to solve problem?

Comment: Yes, `button-press-event` and `button-release-event` are the low-level mouse events for a widget. Buttons handle these by emitting a different signal entirely; for GtkToolButton this is `clicked`. What UI are you trying to do?

Comment: If `change_freq_timeout` is really stuck in a *single instruction*, then how are you supposed to process the events in the first place? In a GUI program, a long-running synchronous operation must be [launched in a separate thread](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html#g-thread-new). This keeps the GUI free to process the incoming events until the operation finishes. Note that the worker thread is not allowed to execute GTK code; it can, however, use `g_idle_add` to tell the GUI thread to do something, or to notify it of the operation's progress.